# Is it possible to append to dataframe through iteration?

Tags: python, pandas

The API response object I am trying to build a dataframe from can be found here: https://github.com/ahoy0/Stack-Overflow-Question/blob/main/SO%20Object

**Edit**  This is one of the most complex data structures I've worked with so far, so any guidance on how to go about this conceptually is appreciated as well.

I previously attempted to append each datapoint (strings) **directly** to the dataframe with a for loop, but was overwriting the previous entry with every iteration.
Following this catastrophic  failure, I opted to do it by creating a series for each column and appending that.
Instead of creating a series and appending that, how could I iterate through the API response without overwriting the previous dataframe index?

Here is my attempt that didnt work:

```
ochain = #(object from above link)
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Strike Price"])
for index in ochain['OptionChainResponse']['OptionPair']:
     df["Strike Price"] = index['Call']['strikePrice']
```

Here is my temporary workaround:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Strike Price"])

strikes = pd.Series(ochain['OptionChainResponse']['OptionPair'][0]['Call']['strikePrice'],
                    ochain['OptionChainResponse']['OptionPair'][1]['Call']['strikePrice'],
                    ochain['OptionChainResponse']['OptionPair'][2]['Call']['strikePrice'],
                    ochain['OptionChainResponse']['OptionPair'][3]['Call']['strikePrice'],
                    ochain['OptionChainResponse']['OptionPair'][4]['Call']['strikePrice'],
                    ochain['OptionChainResponse']['OptionPair'][5]['Call']['strikePrice'],
                    ochain['OptionChainResponse']['OptionPair'][6]['Call']['strikePrice'],
                    ochain['OptionChainResponse']['OptionPair'][7]['Call']['strikePrice'],
                    ochain['OptionChainResponse']['OptionPair'][8]['Call']['strikePrice'],
                    ochain['OptionChainResponse']['OptionPair'][9]['Call']['strikePrice'],
                    ochain['OptionChainResponse']['OptionPair'][10]['Call']['strikePrice'],
                    ochain['OptionChainResponse']['OptionPair'][11]['Call']['strikePrice'],
                    ochain['OptionChainResponse']['OptionPair'][12]['Call']['strikePrice'],
                    ochain['OptionChainResponse']['OptionPair'][13]['Call']['strikePrice'],
                    ochain['OptionChainResponse']['OptionPair'][14]['Call']['strikePrice'],
                    ochain['OptionChainResponse']['OptionPair'][15]['Call']['strikePrice'],
                    ochain['OptionChainResponse']['OptionPair'][16]['Call']['strikePrice'],
                    ochain['OptionChainResponse']['OptionPair'][17]['Call']['strikePrice'],
                    ochain['OptionChainResponse']['OptionPair'][18]['Call']['strikePrice'],
                    ochain['OptionChainResponse']['OptionPair'][19]['Call']['strikePrice'])

df["Strike Price"].append(strikes)
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Produce a minimal reproducible example, provide  your atttempt and what exactly your problem was with it, and expected output. And most importantly, don't for loop in dataframes, unless you really really have to.

Comment: Hi Zabop, please review the changes I made. Does that make it more clear? Thank you for taking the time to respond, I really appreciate that.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but you *definitely* don't want to do things that way. Instead, append to a list then add that list as a column to your dataframe

Comment: Your problem, `df[column] = scalar_value` *doesn't append*. Which should be obvious since you are using a `container[key] = item` syntax, which *generally doesn't append*, it *writes to a specific key*. In this case, for a `pd.DataFrame`, it writes the scalar value to the column*. You *could* use `df.append`, but again, **you shouldn't**

Comment: Also note, this won't work: `df["Strike Price"].append(strikes)`... that creates *a new series* which it immediately discards.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks. So my "temporary workaround" is my best shot. How can I avoid the copy error that you Identified with df["Strike Price"].append(strikes) Instead of a list, is there any benefit in using a series vs a list in this context?

Comment: No just use a list.